# Assembly branch: program counter

Tags: assembly, microcontroller

I'm working with the HCS08 CPU (used in Freescale MCUs) and I can't understand a Branch instruction. Here is the [manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/HCS08RMV1.pdf). The Program Counter in this architecture points to the *next* instruction to be fetched. The BSR instruction (page 237) will update the Program Counter register in the following way (before saving it into the stack and making the branch):

PC ← (PC) + $0002 Advance PC to return address

They say "The program counter is incremented by 2 from the opcode address (so it points to the opcode of the next instruction which will be the return address)".
But why by 2 and not just by 1???
Suppose I have

- line 1 instruction1
- line 2 BSR
- line 3 instruction2
- line 4 instruction3

While the CPU fetches "instruction1" doesn't know that there will be a branch in the next line, so after the "instruction1" fetch the Program Counter points to the line 2. When the CPU fetches the BSR, it doesn't increment the Program Counter; it saves in the Stack the actual value of the Program Counter plus 2, which will be used by the return instruction at the end of the branch. But Program Counter + 2 points to line 4, not to line 3!!! Isn't it an error?
Thank you for having read!

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be getting consused between the assembler *location* counter and the CPU *program* counter. BSR is a 2 byte instruction (AD + addr), so the PC needs to be advanced by 2.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it! Thank you!